# Getting a resource in a another package from within a jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, nullpointerexception

OK, I know this question is asked a lot, but all the solutions I found did not work. I'm currently making an application in netbeans that uses a custom font. The program runs fine in netbeans with zero errors. However when Netbeans cleans and builds the jar and I run it from the command line with:

```
java -jar MyProject.jar
```

The program returns a nullPointerException on the following line:

```
try {
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResource("/fonts/Raleway-ExtraLight.TTF").openStream()); //<--this line
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating font: "+e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

I've tried many different solutions such as:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource();
```

But they to do not work. I've never used streams before, and I feel I may have to recode a major part of my program if I have to use them (I'm loading a lot of images as well, I don't know if they work). I have all my code in one package and my fonts and images next to it in their own packages. All answers welcome. I've only really started programming and would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

(edit) Just wanted to say that I did some more debugging and found that the location of the font is null.

Comment: Is this font in the jar file, or simply on the file system? (In other words, do you intend to deploy it, or is it expected to already be on your target systems?)

Comment: The font is in the jar file, in a folder called fonts.

Comment: This is a guess but it looks like the absolute path ("/fonts/Raleway-ExtraLight.TTF" instead of "fonts/Raleway-ExtraLight.TTF") is causing getResource to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've solved it. By default, if no classpath is set, the classpath is set by default to the folder from which you run the command. This means that my program was looking for the font in the folder that contains my jar, which is the incorrect location as the font is in the jar. You can set the classpath from the command line with -cp, and then all your folder and files (including external jars), separated by colons (;). The problem was completely unrelated to  my code.